# return to the comment page after login

Tags: php

Sorry if I didn't show you the code because I have no idea how to implement it. I just want to know that for instance in YouTube, when you want to make comment on the video, you have to login in, so how to redirect you to the previous video page that you want to make comment. I suppose I need to store the url of the previous page into a session, but if the user didn't login, can I still keep track of the url, Sorry for my confusion. I want to do it in php, can anyone help me with it, thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use something like this too..!!

when the user need to redirected back to a page., lets suppose he wanted to comment on post.php page but when he tries commenting it will redirect to login if not already logged in., so, during yu redirect him to login page, send a get parameter to login page like

http://example.in/login.php?redirect_url=http://example.in/post.php

now handle this get parameter in the login.php page and when the credentials are authenticated you can just redirect him back to the url which is sent through the get parameter..!

your login.php can be something like this

```
$redirect_url = $_GET['redirect_url']; 
if(authenticated)
{
  header("Location: $redirect_url");
}
else
{  }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`header('Location: '. $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);`

This is the easiest way. It will redirect the user automatically to the page he came from, in case he activated referers (default).

Comment: This breaks as soon as the use mistypes his password or the authentication takes more than one page.

Comment: I know, you're right. I think the $_GET way is much better you and Olaf mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the link in the URLs linking to your login page. You can then read the $_GET value out there and handle it accordingly.

Comment: hi, sorry, I have a poor understanding, could you go into a bit detail please

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggesting passing the return URL as GET parameter:

```
$login_url = 'http://example.com/login.php?return=' . rawurlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Using sessions to routinely transmit information between two points can ruin the browsing experience as soon as the use opens multiple tabs.

Once logged in, use [header()](http://php.net/header) to generate an HTTP redirection:

```
if( isset($_GET['return']) && substr($_GET['return'], 0, 1)=='/' ){
    header('Location: http://example.com' . $_GET['return']);
    exit;
}else{
    header('Location: http://example.com/');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: hi, why substr($_GET['return'], 0, 1)=='/'?

Comment: Just to make sure that a scammer is not using our login form to redirect to some other site and possibly make the user re-type his password in that site.

Comment: thanks but there's no '/' in the first character of the return string? sorry for my poor understanding

Comment: @smith - I can't understand your last question. It's only a security check. Remove it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Since every page has to check itself for a logged-in user anyway (authentication), i would not call the login page explicitely. Instead the target page will call it when necessary and stores itself as the login target (session).

Example:

`article.php` needs to call `article_comment.php`, but the comment page needs a login with `login.php`. The login page then should call the comment page after a successful login.

1. `article.php` calls `article_comment.php` directly.
2. The `article_comment.php` page checks if the user is already logged in and calls `login.php` if necessary. Before it does the redirect to the login.php page it stores the login target as itself `$_SESSION['loginTarget'] = 'article_comment.php'`;
3. After the login page has finished successfully, it calls the login target.
   `header('Location: '.$_SESSION['loginTarget'], true, 303); exit;`

This way will not interrupt the natural way of the links (article.php can call article_comment.php directly). Because the login target is stored in the session, you can do error handling on the login page easily, or even create a new user account. The checking of a logged-in user has do be done anyway, why not use it to request a login if necessary?